How to read mixed-endian data from file using Python and numpy?
I have a file where 32-bit float values are stored with standard, little-endian byte order, but with the high-word and low-word of the 32 bits swapped.
I.e. a number that would read 0xDEADBEEF when written as an IEEE-754 float (value approx. 6.26E+18) is stored in the order of 0xBEEFDEAD.
I figured out two ways to do this, but both seem unnecessarily complicated to me:
import numpy as np

# Starting by reading the data as 16-bit words seems to be a good start:
words_in = np.fromfile("data.bin", dtype="uint16")

# Reverse word order, interpret as float and again reverse order of values:
words_backwards = words_in[-1::-1].copy()
float_values_backwards = words_backwards.view(">f4")
float_values = float_values_backwards[-1::-1]

# Above written in one line:
float_values = words_in[-1::-1].copy().view(">f4")[-1::-1]


# Or using reshaping and transpose operations:
float_values = words_in.reshape(-1, 2).T[-1::-1].T.reshape(-1).view(">f4")

Is there an easier or more intuitive way to swap word order but retain byte order in Python?

Byte swap the 16-bit array and view as little-endian float:
import numpy as np

data = bytes.fromhex('beefdead')
org = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.uint16)
fix = org.byteswap().view('<f4')
print(fix)

Output:
[-6.2598534e+18]


Dang! That was easy! It did not occur to me that the ".byteswap()" method also works for swapping words.

And then again, the ".byteswap()" does exactly as it says, it is only that first swapping bytes and then interpreting backwards is equivalent to swapping the high and low word.
